# How to get username from "form login" to funtions.php

Tags: php, forms

I have a trouble with my code. I want to get username from login form to another page in my project, example functions.php
But i don't know how to get that username. I need the username to take the username to the user log. I don't know the algoruthm how to get the username from login_process.php to functions.php.

//Login_process.php

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
    include_once('functions.php'); 

    $username = $_POST['username']; 
    $password = $_POST['password']; 



    $database = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'user', 'library'); 
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM account WHERE username=? AND password=?'; 
    $statement = $database->prepare($query); 
    $statement->bind_param('ss', $username, $password); 
    $statement->execute(); 
    $result_set = $statement->get_result(); 

    if($result_set->num_rows){ 
        $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = TRUE; 
        //$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
        log_visitor(basename(__FILE__));
        redirect('index.php'); 
    }else{ 
        redirect('login.php'); 
    } 
?>
```

//functions.php

```
function log_admin($_page) {
    $file_name = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'log.txt';
    $mode = 'a+';
    $log_file = fopen($file_name, $mode);
    $time = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');


    if(filesize($file_name)==0){
        fwrite($log_file, 'Date'."\t". 'Time'."\t\t\t". 'User'."\t\t". 'File'."\r\n\r\n");
    }

    fwrite($log_file, $time."\t".'#'.$_SESSION['is_logged_in'].'#accessing'."\t" .$_page."\r\n");
    fclose($log_file);
}
```

Comment: You set where you want the username and password to be posted to within the `<form>` element in the `action=""` attribute on your page

Comment: I feel you should call `log_admin` instead of `log_visitor(basename(__FILE__));` or you may have another function in your function.php. Please share the code of that function

Comment: I have made form in another file "login.php" and action "login_process.php", now i want to get the username from the login_process.php to functions.php

Comment: i just have function log_admin and log_visitor. It just how to make a difference if some user have been logged in or not. Now i want to get the username from login_process.php to the log_admin function to write the log to the log.txt

Comment: You are calling `log_visitor` in your Login_process.php. First you should change that to `log_admin`

Comment: But in the login_process, it doesn't loggin yet, so it still visitor not the user/admin

Comment: as per your code you are calling `log_visitor` in your Login_process.php but asking question about `log_admin`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the username from another file you can store it in the $_SESSION superglobal.

After `$_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = true;` you can store another session variable for the username.

You can then access that in your `functions.php` file using the $_SESSION superglobal after you've added `session_start();` to the file.

Comment: I've made $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'], but i got error while compiling the project

Answer (score 0):

Just register the username also in the `$_SESSION` variable. It is a superglobal, so available everywhere. Just don't forget to call `session_start` in the script that uses `functions.php`.

You seem to be doing it already, as you commented out that portion:

```
if($result_set->num_rows){ 
    $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = TRUE; 
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
    log_visitor(basename(__FILE__));
    redirect('index.php'); 
}else{ 
    redirect('login.php'); 
}
```

(Final note: don't store passwords plaintext, use a hashing algorithm instead)

Comment: But i dont know how to register the username in the $_SESSION variable. Can you help me fellas? :D

Comment: @DanielBoyMarpaung you are doing it: `$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username']`. That's it, just assign a `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: I've made like that, but i got error while compiling the program. Error in functions.php that have the $_SESSION['user'] variable

Comment: What error? Make sure you call `session_start` at the beginning of the script that uses `functions.php`.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\IBAD\Week4Sesi01_part2\functions.php on line 20

Comment: this is the code that error
 fwrite($log_file, $time."\t".'#'.$_SESSION['username'].'#accessing'."\t" .$_page."\r\n");

Comment: Note the difference between `$_SESSION['user']` and `$_SESSION['username']`.

Comment: I've made both of them, bit i still got the same error